# XSLT:How to Maintain Sequential Order of tag in XML

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have Input XML.In that,We are not able to maintain sequential order of tag.
Basically,We have written transformation in XSLT.Then it also harms sequential order of 2 Looping tag.

We wanted to Maintain Sequential Order using `<UserDefined>` Tag.

**Input XML:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>
         <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
           </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Ensure saddle is color coded</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810127</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>10</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-001</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810128</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>11</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-PREVIOUS</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810129</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>12</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>ACSH-NHH-12OZ-12</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>NHH ABYSS CHIA SHAMPOO 12OZ CS</StockDescription>
            <OrderUom>CS</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>CS</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>13</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810130</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>PAD-DISPLAY-SMH-26</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>PAD TARGET ASSORTMENT 2</StockDescription>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>14</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810131</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>LADO-SMO-4OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMO LAVENDER DRY OIL 4OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>7.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>1</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1634834</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>WSSB-SMS-6OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMW COCONUT SHAVE BUTTER 6OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>7.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>2</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1636755</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHCM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH COCONUT MILK 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>6</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1641836</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHWS-SMO-03</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SPECIAL2 COCONUT HM/CM/CC</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>25.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>4</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1642378</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHHM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH COCONUT HAIR MIST 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>7</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1642587</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHCC-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH CH COWASH CLEANSER 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>5</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1652357</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>10.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>3</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1659227</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810124</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>8</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-SAVE</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810125</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>9</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

**We tried XSLT On it.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="StockLine[not(StockCodeDescription) and not (OrderQty) and not(Price)]">
      <CommentLine>
         <Comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="StockCode" />
         </Comment>
         <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="UserDefined" />
      </CommentLine>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="CommentLine">
      <CommentLine>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="CommentLine" group-by="CommentLine">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </CommentLine>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="CommentLine[OrderLineID = preceding-sibling::StockLine/OrderLineID and not(Comment)]" />
   <xsl:template match="CommentLine[some $sib in preceding-sibling::CommentLine satisfies deep-equal(., $sib)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>
         <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>LADO-SMO-4OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMO LAVENDER DRY OIL 4OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>7.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>1</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1634834</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>WSSB-SMS-6OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMW COCONUT SHAVE BUTTER 6OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>7.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>2</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1636755</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>10.99</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>3</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1659227</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHWS-SMO-03</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SPECIAL2 COCONUT HM/CM/CC</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>25.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>4</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1642378</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHCC-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH CH COWASH CLEANSER 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>5</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1652357</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHCM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH COCONUT MILK 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>6</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1641836</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>CHHM-SMH-8OZ-01</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>SMH COCONUT HAIR MIST 8OZ</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>7</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1642587</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810124</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>8</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-SAVE</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810125</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>9</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Ensure saddle is color coded</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810127</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>10</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-001</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810128</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>11</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>EDI-PREVIOUS</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810129</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>12</UserDefined>
         </CommentLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>ACSH-NHH-12OZ-12</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>NHH ABYSS CHIA SHAMPOO 12OZ CS</StockDescription>
            <OrderUom>CS</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>CS</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>13</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810130</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>PAD-DISPLAY-SMH-26</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>PAD TARGET ASSORTMENT 2</StockDescription>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <Price>0.0</Price>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>14</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810131</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

Comment: Csn you post the XML output you want and then one you get and explain in more detail which problems you face? You have some grouping code in there matching `CommentLine` elements but then trying to group `CommentLine` child elements which is not a structure present anywhere in your sample.

Comment: Sure <UserDefined> this tag is having number. Using this number we have to Sort in Ascending Order. I  am also  trying to post arranged output XML.

Comment: Attached is the Expected Output In edited question.All we want to look <UserDefined> tag which is common for  both the  tag CommentLine and StockLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to sort the child elements of the `OrderDetails` element by the `UserDefined` element value then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(UserDefined)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

suffices (Online at http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjt). I am however not sure why you include all those other templates that seem unrelated.

Comment: It was my greediness of getting Output. I forget to Include Namespace  xs. When Iincluded  it is working correctly. Thanks a ton Martin.

Comment: I am however not sure why you include all those other templates that seem unrelated. ---- I tried it  if you f0und unrelated or syntax wise wrong .please help me on that what is not relavant in XSLT.